# Firestore permission error in test database mode

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, permissions, firebase-security

I know that questions about Firestore permission errors have been asked a lot, but my situation may be unique. This is because of three things:

1. my database is in test mode which should allow access to anyone (right?)
2. I am getting the error while simulating my app with an authenticated firebase user
3. I am able to write data--the error only happened while reading it.

Here are my security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
          allow read, write: if
              request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 12, 31);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of a description of Firestore's test database mode:

[image]

The actual error I got was this:

```
Error: Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13021 "User does not have permission 
to access gs://zimmerfour.appspot.com/senderID." UserInfo={object=senderID, 
ResponseBody={
    "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied. Please enable Firebase Storage for your bucket by visiting the Storage tab in the Firebase Console and ensure that you have sufficient permission to properly provision resources."
```

EDIT:

I haven't changed the overall Cloud Storage rules. They are still set to the default of:

```
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
       allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is coming from Cloud Storage for Firebase (as indicated by `FIRStorageErrorDomain` and the error message), which is protected by its own set of [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/rules-conditions) in your project.

Comment: I am using the default Cloud Storage rules, which should work for my simulated user (which is authenticated). Note that I've also been able to access images stored in my Cloud Storage in the same session as I got this error. What am I missing?

Comment: This really should be a new post, but I'll try to help further here. Did you associate the bucket with Firebase? This error message seems to hint that may be the problem: "Please enable Firebase Storage for your bucket by visiting the Storage tab in the Firebase Console and ensure that you have sufficient permission to properly provision resources."

Comment: The rules I am referring to belong to the Storage section of my Firebase app. (i.e. Auth, Realtime, Storage, Firestore). Is there a different set of "Storage" rules that you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Try this method, it worked for me :)

```
// if you want to allow for all to read, write

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}


// if you want to allow for all to read, and authenticated users to write

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}

// if you want to allow for only authenticated users to write or read

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```